# My fire has extremly low resolution

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire, resolution, mantaflow

I started experimenting with fire and smoke and now i have the problem that my fire and smoke both have are in terrible resolution.
I know that the Resolution Devisions are just on 64 but I also tried it with 128 and 256, but both just even worst. It had a bit better resolution but there was much much less fire at all and i wasnt dense at all.
How can i get a good dense fire with good quality?
[image: screenshot of low resolution fire]
[image: Settings of domain]
[image: Settings of inflow]
[image: texture-nodes of the domain]

Comment: You showed wrong setting, go to your smoke settings, what resoĺution are you using? Try to give it higher number

Comment: Is your Noise enabled (higher res flames).  See 1:40 into https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSYMjhFXcr8 ... also what is the object type of the Inflow?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Noise enabled (higher res flames), and are you using a Texture  on the domain? See at time 1:40 and beyond in this [example video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=vSYMjhFXcr8)  ... also what is the object type of the Inflow?

My example [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a bit, but its still not good. I now tried it with resolution devisions of 128 and noise Upres factor at 3.